# Calculator - thousand separator by comma in c#

Tags: c#

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string value = TextBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
double dbl;
if (double.TryParse(value, out dbl))
{
    TextBox.TextChanged -= TextBoxTextChanged;
    TextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:#,#0}", dbl);
    TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.Text.Length;
    TextBox.TextChanged += TextBoxTextChanged;
}
```

}

I used above code for making Calculator. I want to get results comma with decimal value. I want to type 1,234.1234 in the

textBox, but I can not type 1,234.1234 in the Text Box. I mean comma with decimal value not getting.

Can anybody kindly please help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: I can't understand why are you assigning an event handler inside the same event handler... 
TextBox.TextChanged += TextBoxTextChanged; Any case, you need to use CultureInfo to format the number for specific culture

Comment: @Oscar. it looks like the intent is to turn off the event handler (`-=`), change the text, then turn it back on (`+=`). This is to presumably stop the assignment to `TextBox.Text` from infinitely recursing the event.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a Culture that uses . as thousands sign.
Normally you want to use the users current culture.

```
double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out dbl)
```

Comment: Sorry Wertzui, it is no working. I want to type 1000.123 but I can not type it !

Comment: parsing the string "1000.123" with the above code does work. Based on your culture the result is either 1000123 or 1000.123.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int value = 300000
String.Format("{0:#,###0}", value);
// will return 300,000
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx